Issue with AsyncLocalStorage in Next.js 14: context is not being shared between middleware, handlers and SSR pages
I am experiencing issues with sharing the context between Middleware, API Handlers, and SSR Pages in a Next.js 14 project using AsyncLocalStorage. Even though the context is correctly set in the middleware, it does not propagate to API handlers or server-rendered pages.
Here is a simplified example that reproduces the problem:
// utils/asyncLocalStorage.ts
import { AsyncLocalStorage } from 'async_hooks';

const asyncLocalStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();
export default asyncLocalStorage;

// middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import asyncLocalStorage from './utils/asyncLocalStorage';

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  return asyncLocalStorage.run({}, async () => {
    const store = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
    if (store) {
      store.key1 = test;
    }
    return NextResponse.next();
  });
}

// pages/api/hello.ts
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import asyncLocalStorage from '../../utils/asyncLocalStorage';

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const store = asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
  console.log(store); //Here the store is undefined
  res.status(200).send();
}

Is this an expected issue or I'm missing something?

I'm experiencing the exact same problem, we must be missing something...

Apparently middleware and route handlers are executed in different runtimes so they can't share the AsyncLocalStorage :(

Same problem here.
Does it mean AsyncLocalStorage is ruled out for NextJS if trying to add some context-propagation to logging? Or is it somehow possible with some tweaks?
Any other lightweight solution to add context prop to a logging tool in NextJS? I know about OpenTelemetry but it's too heavy for my needs.
